# Best practice when working with many similar database tables with Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have hundreds of tables in a spatial database for various features. Each of these tables have common fields such as ID, Name, Geometry, DateAdded, etc, as well as a number of unique fields specific to each given table.

My applicaiton will receive rows of data which I will need to add to the correct table in the database. Occasionally I will need to update a row too but **I will only ever need to query by the common attributes**.

I would like to know if there is a 'best practice' approach for achieving this functionality using Spring Boot.

---

**My current approach which has a bad code smell**

Currently I have a working prototype using a small subset of the features I will need in the final application. However the approach I have so far seems very verbose and doesn't smell right. I'm sure there must be a better way!

Currently I have:

- An `@Entity` Class for each feature (each extending a Class annotated with `@MappedSuperclass` so that I'm not repeating code related to the common fields).
- A Spring Data JPA Repository for each `@Entity` Class. These have no real code in them other than a FindByIdAndVersionDate query.
- A `@Service` Class which handles calling the correct Repository depending on the data received.

This approach will work but ultimately I will end up with 100 or so largely identical Repository interfaces. It seems to me that it should be possible to have some sort of generic repository into which I can pass a Class definition to figure out which table the data should be added to?

---

I am not wedded to Spring Data JPA. I suspect this would be easier if I took a step back and just used Hibernate (perhaps a generic DAO or something?). If that is the case feel free to let me know!

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Spring solution

You can use `Inheritance.TABLE_PER_PAGE` strategy on your super class, like:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class SuperA {
}
```

This way via your `SuperARepository`, you can store and retrieve all subclasses.

One problem is that when you query to find an object, hibernate performs a **union query of all data** from all tables. It might impose a significant performance overhead in your case.

Another problem is that when you query for a subclass (like `SubA1`), you still receive `SuperA` and you need to downcast to get access to the actual class.

#### JPA solution

I would recommend JPA in this case (JPA is a specification, Hibernate is one of JPA providers). It's better to use generic JPA interfaces, instead of Hibernate specific. You mentioned a **generic DAO** and it's a good approach.

In JPA, your mapping with `@MappedSuperclass` is optimal. You just use `EntityManager` to issue queries.

The only potential problem is if you need to query for an object without knowing its type. However, I assume you must know the type as those are different tables in a database.

The example:

```java
// in Spring Boot it's easy to get access to EntityManager
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager

// you need to annotate your methods/class with @Transactional

// insert a new object, any entity
entityManager.persist(object);

// update an object, any entity
entityManager.merge(object);

// find an object, you need to specify a class
// but no need to downcast as it was in Spring repo (!)
SubA1 found = entityManager.find(SubA1.class, id);
```